# Wightman function for massless vector fields in Coulomb gauge

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, vector-fields, greens-functions

I've been looking for quite some time an expression for the Wightman functions for a massless vector field in the Coulomb gauge $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A}=0$ (I think it is equivalent to the Feynman gauge since using Maxwell's equations and Coulomb gauge we can make $\phi=\text{const}$, and therefore have $\nabla_\mu A^\mu=0$) for the Minkowski vacuum, but I have not quite succeeded. Instead, I have found thermal Wightman functions for the Fulling vacuum [here](http://cds.cern.ch/record/285416/files/9507139.pdf), and the same for an arbitrary gauge in Eq. (2.17) [here](http://cds.cern.ch/record/447183/files/0007138.pdf) (I believe that in this case it would suffice to do $\xi\to 1$ and $\beta\to 0$?).

The closest I have got is with the aid of Eqs. (6), (7) of [this](http://www.actaphys.uj.edu.pl/_old/sup6/pdf/s6p0359.pdf), in which a general form is given which depends on a given function and another (unspecified) dependent on the gauge.

Could anyone therefore point me out which is the expression for the Wightman functions of a massless, free vector field in the Minkowski vacuum and in the Coulomb gauge $\left<0\right|A_i(\mathbf{x},t)A_j(\mathbf{y},t')\left|0\right>$, or at least some guidance on how to obtain it from the results above? Thank you really much.

Comment: I strongly believe that the appropriate expression is the one given in [the third reference](http://www.actaphys.uj.edu.pl/_old/sup6/pdf/s6p0359.pdf) when doing $\Phi_\mu=0$, i.e, being just the scalar Wightman function times the metric. A similar result is found in Eq. (12) [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.7333.pdf), but could anyone confirm it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So actually I just computed it by hand from the very beginning. Starting from the expression of the field $A_i(\mathbf{x},t)=\sum_s\int\frac{\text{d}^3\mathbf{k}}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^3 2|\mathbf{k}|}}\left[a_s(\mathbf{k})\epsilon_i(\mathbf{k},s)e^{i(|\mathbf{k}|t-\mathbf{k\cdot x})}+\text{H.c.}\right]$ where $\epsilon_i(\mathbf{k},s),\,s=1,2,\, i=1,2$ are orthonormal polarization vectors perpendicular to $\mathbf{k}$ and $[a_s(\mathbf{k}),a^\dagger_s(\mathbf{k}')]=\delta_{s,s'}\delta(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}')$, the Wightman function takes the form

$W_{ij}(\mathbf x,\mathbf y,t,t')=\int\frac{\text{d}^3\mathbf k}{(2\pi)^32|\mathbf k|}\sum_{s}\epsilon_i(\mathbf k,s)\epsilon_j(\mathbf k,s)e^{-i |\mathbf{k}|(t-t')}e^{i \mathbf{k}\cdot (\mathbf{x}- \mathbf{y})}$

And now, using for example Eq. (1) in page 36 of "Photons and Atoms: An introduction to Quantum Electrodynamycs" by Cohen-Tannoudji we simply get

$W_{ij}(\mathbf x,\mathbf y,t,t')=\left(\delta_{ij}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right)\int\frac{\text{d}^3\mathbf k}{(2\pi)^32|\mathbf k|}\frac{e^{-i |\mathbf{k}|(t-t')}e^{i \mathbf{k}\cdot (\mathbf{x}- \mathbf{y})}}{|\mathbf{k}|^2}$

The only drawback of this is that the integral diverges at the origin, but I guess that there is not much more one can do.